# Cannot edit MATLAB GUI due to recursion loading

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have been editing a MATLAB gui in guide, no problems until I try to run at which point it crashes.

I then try to edit the GUI but i get the same problem trying to open the fig and MATLAB crashes. I'm using version ....

The error message keeps repeating when crashing but part of it is...

```
??? Error using ==> struct2handle
Error while evaluation uicontrol CreateFcn

??? Error using ==> hgload at 156
Recursion occurs when loading
C:\Users\...\guifile2.fig

Error in openfig at 72
 [fig, savedvisible] = hgload(filename, struct('Visible','off'));

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn>local_openfig at 286

...

Error in ==>guifile at 19
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)guifile2('DD2_CreatFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata...
```

Comment: I know it is too late, but hope it will help someone. It seems like this problem was very similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093223/matlabs-runs-wrong-script-after-figure-copying

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlabs runs wrong script after figure copying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093223/matlabs-runs-wrong-script-after-figure-copying)