# Matlabs runs wrong script after figure copying

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have the following problem. Let us say, we have some GUI written in Matlab. Let it be 
`mygui.fig` and `mygui.m`.

OK, now I want to rewrite this gui and keep prev version of it. So, I copy these two files to `mygui_new.fig` and `mygui_new.m`.

We all know, that when we run `something.fig`, Matlab tries to find `something.m` in order to perform responses on our actions. However, when I'm trying to run my mygui_new.m, Matlab tries to read scripts from mygui.m giving me warnings like:

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: ..\..\matlab\PostProcess\ 

  In path at 110
  In addpath at 87
  In mygui at 22
  In @(hObject,eventdata)SemiSuperviseTool_main('video_name_popupmenu_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
  In graphics/private/hgloadStructDbl at 95
  In /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/matlab/graphics/hgload.p>hgload at 70
  In openfig at 72
  In gui_mainfcn>local_openfig at 286
  In gui_mainfcn at 159
  In mygui_new at 46
```

So, we see that Matlab is really starting from my new version of script, but then for some reason tries to load an old one. If I delete old files at all, GUI will not run.

Here is another my post:
[No breakpoints after gui figure copying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849773/no-breakpoints-after-gui-figure-copying)

The solutions I've described there doest not work here.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIG file stores tags and callbacks that have names tied to the original M file. So, to truly replicate, one has to at least edit those changes for the new FIG file using GUIDE.

Comment: Oh, now I can really see it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a replication of a GUI? Without stupid manual renaming all the stuff?

Comment: Not sure if there's any other way out, sorry.